# Edit strings.xml file content in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I want to allow the users to enter in text using the settings template in android studio.
And display this in a textview.(which is already set)

settings_activity_settings.xml
is

```
    <resources>
    <string name="title_activity_settings">Settings</string>
    <!-- General settings -->
    <string name="pref_header_general">General</string>

    <string name="pref_title_display_name">Enter Team 1</string>

    <string name="pref_title_display_name_2">Enter Team 2</string>


</resources>
```

how to i retrieve this data

Comment: getResourse().getString(R.string. pref_header_general)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your approach is not correct.

Because, you can't change resource files during runtime. Strings are hard-coded in the string.xml file and hence can't be changed during runtime.

I suggest you read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/overview.html), it will help you understand why android framework don't want you to edit the file in runtime.

Now, the solution to your problem? Simple, save the string you get from user in to Shared Preference and load it int text views from there.

Comment: Thanks. I thought there was something about strings and run time.

Comment: I havent had a chance to try it yet. but looks like the right idea